# Block for plotting a function using different parameters

Tags: plotting

I want to plot `height[time]` function for different values of `M` and `g`. This function contains `a[2]` which needs to be found. I had two-coupled algebraic equation for `a[2]` and `t[2]`. I used `Solve` to solve that system and it worked. However the issue starts at that point, when I execute below code, it does not produce a graph. I did something wrong, but the question is "where". Please see below;

```
p01[x_] := Integrate[2*a[2]/k*1/(x - c) + t[2]/k , {x, 0, x},Assumptions -> 0 < x < c] + 1/2

p02[x_] := Integrate[2*a[2]/k*1/(x - c) + t[2]/k , {x, 1, x},Assumptions -> c < x < 1] 

first[x_] := Integrate[p01[x], {x, 0, c}, Assumptions -> 0 < c < 1]

second[x_] := Integrate[p02[x], {x, c, 1}, Assumptions -> 0 < c < 1]

third[x_] := Integrate[(x - c)*p01[x], {x, 0, c}, Assumptions -> 0 < c < 1]

fourth[x_] := Integrate[(x - c)*p02[x], {x, c, 1}, Assumptions -> 0 < c < 1]

Solve[2*M*a[2] == first[x]+second[x] - M*g && 2*M*i*t[2] ==third[x]+fourth[x], {a[2], t[2]}]

c = 0.4; k = 1; i = 0.2;

a[0] = k*c*(1 - c);
t[0] = k*(1 - 2*c);

height[time_] := a[0] + time^2*a[2]

plot4 = Block[{M = {0, 0.1, 1, 10}, g = {0, 0.1, 1, 10}}, 
  Plot[Evaluate@height[time], {time, 0, 1}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue, Black}]]
```

Comment: These is no question in this post.  If there's a problem with your code and you want it solved, please state it clearly, and construct a complete but minimal example.  Post no more code than what is needed to reproduce the problem.  That will certainly be less than what's here.  See http://sscce.org/ for guidance.

Comment: Thanks @Szabolcs, I have edited the post. The issue is plotting in this above code. It does not give me a graph. Might be because of the definition of parameters. I cannot figure it out!

Comment: it seem, that $b$ in third[] and fourth[] is not defined. furthermore: in the definition of heigth[] a[2] has to be replaced by the solution a[2] from Solve[]: (sol = Solve[
  2*M*a[2] == first[x] + second[x] - M*g && 
   2*M*i*t[2] == third[x] + fourth[x], {a[2], t[2]}] and height[time_] := a[0] + time^2*a[2] /.  sol[[1, 1]])

Comment: @Armin, thanks to your comment, I changed `b` to `c`. It was a typo. Anyway it still does not work. Also a big thank you for the second part of your comment about dividing sol[[1,1]] . So is sol[[2,1]] for t[2] then??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look, there are several issues with your code which is why it is important that *you* tear the pieces apart before posting a question. I'm sure you could have solved this yourself.

1. You don't use the solution for `a[2]` and `t[2]`. You call `Solve` correctly, but you don't store the solution and use it in `Plot`.
2. You have a mystical `b` in your code-block that never gets a value.

Want to know how you easily find all this issues? One easy way is always to **not** use `Plot` because then you only see an empty graph. What I usually do is to type `Plott` which is a function that is not defined and therefore, nothing happens except that you really see the parameters. So after evaluating your code-block do (see the `Plott`!):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now you see that there is an unevaluated `a[2]` in there. So the first thing you do is to store the solution of `Solve`

```
sol = 
 Flatten@Solve[
   2*M*a[2] == first[x] + second[x] - M*g && 
    2*M*i*t[2] == third[x] + fourth[x], {a[2], t[2]}]
```

and use it

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now, you see that your formula contains the `b` which needs a value. I'll set it to `b=1` in the `Block` and replace `Plott` with `Plot` again and there you have it

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: this is great answer, thanks so much. As you posted I did sol = 
 Flatten@Solve[
   2*M*a[2] == first[x] + second[x] - M*g && 
    2*M*i*t[2] == third[x] + fourth[x], {a[2], t[2]}]   but a[2] is still not recognised.  Then I used `height[time_] := a[0] + time^2*a[2] /. sol[[1, 1]]` but the outcome for height[time] is `0.24+t^2a[2] a[2]`. I started kernel then evaluated again all, but it did not revealed.

Comment: Here is the exact code that I used: `Import["http://goo.gl/NaH6rM"]["http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrHmp.png"]`
Please copy and evaluate the complete import statement.

Comment: I am so thankful @halirutan, but I guess the content of those links are not so relevant e.g it says the png file is no longer available, so I cannot see what is inside. But again, thanks..

Comment: That is very weird. It is the first time that imgur deleted an image. Please try this one `Import["http://goo.gl/NaH6rM"]["http://i.stack.imgur.com/1DsxV.png"]`
At this moment the image is available. I don't know for how long..

Comment: Unfortunately not @halirutan. So, should I try this : `height[time_] := a[0] + time^2*a[2] /. sol[[1, 1]]` , but as I say, it still does not give a[2] . I understand Mathematica can't assign the results of a Solve to the unknowns because there may be more than 1 solution.

Comment: Would you like to join the [chat] for a second?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46859/discussion-between-meva-and-halirutan).